# How to reduce the execution time in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've work to below sql query:

```
WITH courses AS
        (
            select custom_courses.module_id, student_id, custom_courses.course_name, custom_courses.pass_level, custom_courses.cc_id, assign_date,
                0 as fromComplete, completion_date, company_id
            from student_adhoc_courses WITH (NOLOCK)
                inner join custom_courses WITH (NOLOCK) on custom_courses.cc_id = student_adhoc_courses.cc_id
            UNION all

            select custom_courses.module_id, student_id, custom_courses.course_name, custom_courses.pass_level, custom_courses.cc_id, assign_date,
                0 as fromComplete, student_courses.completion_date, company_id
            from student_courses WITH (NOLOCK)
                inner join custom_courses WITH (NOLOCK) on custom_courses.cc_id = student_courses.cc_id
                UNION all

                select custom_courses.module_id, student_id, custom_courses.course_name, custom_courses.pass_level, custom_courses.cc_id,
                    null as assign_date, 1 as fromComplete, null as completion_date, company_id
                from student_courses_completed WITH (NOLOCK)
                    inner join custom_courses on custom_courses.cc_id = student_courses_completed.cc_id
        ),


select distinct

s.student_last +', '+ s.student_first name,
s.login_id as login,
s.phone as phone,
s.email as email
from students s
where s.company_id in ('1000004')
```

**In this query using union all method**
so this query take more time(16 mins) can be execute.
so can you please any one to reduce the query execute time.

Comment: This is unanswerable I'm afraid. You need to do your own performance testing. Go take a look at the execution plan, find out which part is slow. You haven't given us that or even the table structure, indexes etc.

Comment: Stop using nolock hint - it is not a magic "speed booster" and has implications you need to understand. Your query, as posted, makes no use of your cte so **remove it**. The use of distinct is suspicious when selecting rows from a table named "students" - is not every row a unique instance of a particular student?

Comment: right off the bat my suggestions are to insert each part into temp table (index the temp table if you have to) . Then use a CTE to build the logic you are doing now and finally, while you are at it replace Union All with Union because your now gaming with temp tables.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have all the indexes there?
* student_adhoc_courses.cc_id
* custom_courses.cc_id (for the code it seems is Primary key here)
* student_courses.cc_id
* student_courses_completed.cc_id

Comment: This is not an answer - it should be posted as a comment.